# GLTF file is loading but it displaying black in browser three.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, three.js

I am working on my project in Django where I am using three.js to load my model and animate it I was able to load my .gltf file but it getting displayed black on my browser my website background color is white
even though it's showing the black screen.**I am totally new to the Three.js pls guide me**

here is my code

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'mysite/style.css' %}" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/threejs/r76/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/92/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mrdoob/three.js@r92/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
 
    <title>Finance Assistant</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas class="webgl"></canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Debug
//const gui = new dat.GUI()

const gltfloader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

// Canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas.webgl')

// Scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene()

//Hand
gltfloader.load("{% static 'mysite/HomeHand.gltf' %}", function(gltf) {
  scene.add(gltf.scene);

  });

/* Objects
const geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry( .7, .2, 16, 100 );

// Materials

const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()
material.color = new THREE.Color(0xff0000)

// Mesh
const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material)
scene.add(sphere)
*/
// Lights

const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.1)
pointLight.position.x = 2
pointLight.position.y = 3
pointLight.position.z = 4
scene.add(pointLight)

/**
 * Sizes
 */
const sizes = {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
}

window.addEventListener('resize', () =>
{
    // Update sizes
    sizes.width = window.innerWidth
    sizes.height = window.innerHeight

    // Update camera
    camera.aspect = sizes.width / sizes.height
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix()

    // Update renderer
    renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
    renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
})

/**
 * Camera
 */
// Base camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width / sizes.height, 0.1, 100)
camera.position.x = 0
camera.position.y = 0
camera.position.z = 500
scene.add(camera)

// Controls
// const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas)
// controls.enableDamping = true

/**
 * Renderer
 */
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvas,
    alpha:true
})
renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))

/**
 * Animate
 */
const clock = new THREE.Clock()

const tick = () =>
{

    const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime()

    // Update objects
    //sphere.rotation.y = .5 * elapsedTime

    // Update Orbital Controls
    // controls.update()

    // Render
    renderer.render(scene, camera)

    // Call tick again on the next frame
    window.requestAnimationFrame(tick)
}

tick()
      </script>
      
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Can you create a demo out of it? https://codesandbox.io/